# プロキシサーバを使用しないことでSSL-VPN接続ができる理由がよくわかりません

Tags: vpn, proxy

先日IE11ブラウザでゲートウェイサーバにSSL-VPN接続した際(L2フォワーディング方式)、ブラウザに

```
接続されていません。プロキシサーバは応答していません
```

と表示されました。

LAN設定にある
「プロキシサーバを使用する」
のチェックを外すことでゲートウェイサーバにSSL-VPN接続ができました。

しかし、なぜプロキシサーバを使用しないことでSSL-VPN接続ができるのか理由がよくわかっておりません。
原因として証明書が絡んだりするものなのでしょうか？

初歩的な質問で大変恐縮ではありますがご教示いただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: SSL-VPNゲートウェイサーバーのソフトは何でしょうか？Cisco AnyConnectとか、FortiGateとか、Ivanti(Pulse Secure)とか、F5とか、そういった製品名またはメーカーはわかりますか？(製品によって、細かい動作が異なります)

Comment: お使いのOSは何でしょうか？Win10/11では、EdgeのIE11モードを除き、通常のIE11を使用することはできません。IE11を使用したというのであれば、古いWindowsか、サーバーOSか、パッチを適用していないWin10等が考えられ、それらの影響も考えられます。

Comment: raccyさん
コメントありがとうございます！
借りている端末のためソフトの名称は不明ですが、OSはWindows10 Enterpriseです。

Comment: IE11でアクセスした時に、製品名かメーカー名が表示されるはずです。それがわからないというのであれば、IE11に接続したときのスクリーンショットを撮って質問に貼り付けてください。

Comment: Win10Enterpriseの場合、LTSB/LTSCのバージョンによって細かい動作が異なる場合や既知の不具合が残ったままである場合があります。バージョンも質問に明記してください。(バージョンはWindowsキーとPause/Breakキーを同時に押すと確認できます)